# scrollbar on browser window - viewport, not on a inner element

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have created an application in Vue-Vuetify, and I want to use flexbox and scrolling on a listview.

[codesandbox list view](https://codesandbox.io/s/list-tabs-hnm34q)

I don't know why, but I struggle to create a scrollbar on the inner element in a v-list-item; it always appears on the browser window (viewport).

Can someone explain why I am having this problem?